# email sending failed in C# windows application with windows 7 32-bit operating System

Tags: c#-4.0

i have developed code in C# for sending multiple emails with multiple attachment. 
In widows 7,8 with 64 bits operating system not getting problem and sending mails is successfully. But when i trying in 32-bit operation system it is getting error "Email sending failure" or unable to connect remote server, so what should i do for sending my mail with attachment through windows 32-bit in c# application

```
enter code here
        //try
        //{
            //timer1.Start();
            progressBar1.Visible = true;
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            this.crystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
            int d = Convert.ToInt32(strUserId1);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Customer_Info where billno=" + d + "", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            string customeremail;
            string subject;
            customeremail = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[10].ToString();

            subject = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[13].ToString();


            //Report crp = new Report();
            TaxInvoice po = new TaxInvoice();
            po.SetDataSource(dt);
            po.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\\TaxInvoice.rpt");
            //rd.Load("StudentReg.rpt");
            po.SetDataSource(dt);
            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = po;
            crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
            if (File.Exists(@"E:\Demand letters\" + customeremail + ".pdf"))
                File.Delete(@"E:\Demand letters\" + customeremail + ".pdf");
            po.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, @"E:\Demand letters\" + customeremail + ".pdf");
            string path = "E:\\Demand letters\\" + customeremail + ".pdf";
            System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com",587);
            mail.From = new MailAddress("chavan.shekhar1989@gmail.com");
            da.Fill(dt);

            if (dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[10].ToString() == "" || dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[10].ToString() == null)
            {
            }
            else
            {
                customeremail = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[10].ToString();
                mail.To.Add(customeremail);
            }
            mail.Subject = subject;//"Demmand Letter";
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            string htmlBody;
            htmlBody = "Thank You,";
            mail.Body = htmlBody;
           // SmtpServer.Port = 587;//587
            SmtpServer.Credentials = new
            System.Net.NetworkCredential("xyz@gmail.com", "password");
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
            Attachment a = new Attachment("E:\\Demand letters\\" + customeremail + ".pdf");
            mail.Attachments.Add(a);
            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
            progressBar1.Visible = false;
           // timer1.Stop();
            MessageBox.Show("Mail has been sent Successfully.", "meanform", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

Comment: did you check the firewall? maybe your app blocked so it unable to connect to remote server

Comment: yes i have already checked firewall it is on position. so what should i do can i make firewall off

Comment: so you confirm that by turning firewall off your app starts working?